# Combining many ReactiveX streams into one result stream

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java2, reactivex

I am trying to understand ReactiveX using RxJava but I can't get the whole Reactive idea. My case is the following:

I have `Task` class. It has `perform()` method which is executing an HTTP request and getting a response through `executeRequest()` method. The request may be executed many times (defined number of repetitions). I want to grab all the results of `executeRequest()` and combine them into `Flowable` data stream so I can return this `Flowable` in `perform()` method. So in the end I want my method to return all results of the requests that my `Task` executed.

`executeRequest()` returns `Single` because it executes only one request and may provide only one response or not at all (in case of timeout). 
In `perform()` I create `Flowable` range of numbers for each repetition. Subscribed to this `Flowable` I execute a request per repetition. I additionally subscribe to each response `Single` for logging and gathering responses into a collection for later. So now I have a set of `Single`s, how can I merge them into `Flowable` to return it in `perform()`? I tried to mess around with operators like `merge()` but I don't understand its parameters types.

I've read some guides on the web but they all are very general or don't provide examples according to my case.

```
public Flowable<HttpClientResponse> perform() {

    Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<HttpClientResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> failedRepetitionNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    Flowable.rangeLong(0, repetitions)
            .subscribe(repetition -> {
                logger.debug("Performing repetition {} of {}", repetition + 1, repetitions);

                Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (durationCap == 0 || currentTime - startTime < durationCap) {

                    Single<HttpClientResponse> response = executeRequest(method, url, headers, body);

                    response.subscribe(successResult -> {
                                logger.info("Received response with code {} in the {}. repetition.", successResult
                                        .statusCode(), repetition + 1);
                                responses.add(successResult);
                            },
                            error -> {
                                logger.error("Failed to receive response from {}.", url);
                                failedRepetitionNumbers.add(repetition);
                            });
                    waitInterval(minInterval, maxInterval);
                } else {
                    logger.info("Reached duration cap of {}ms for task {}.", durationCap, this);
                }
            });

    return Flowable.merge(???);
}
```

And `executeRequest()`

```
private Single<HttpClientResponse> executeRequest(HttpMethod method, String url, LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>
        headers, JsonNode body) {

    CompletableFuture<HttpClientResponse> responseFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

    HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = client.request(method, url, responseFuture::complete);
    headers.forEach(request::putHeader);
    request.write(body.toString());
    request.setTimeout(timeout);
    request.end();

    return Single.fromFuture(responseFuture);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subscribing to each observable(each HTTP request) within your `perform` method, Just keep on chaining the observables like this. Your code can be reduced to something like.

```
    public Flowable<HttpClientResponse> perform() {
    // Here return a flowable , which can emit n number of times. (where n = your number of HTTP requests)
    return Flowable.rangeLong(0, repetitions) // start a counter
            .doOnNext(repetition -> logger.debug("Performing repetition {} of {}", repetition + 1, repetitions)) // print the current count
            .flatMap(count -> executeRequest(method, url, headers, body).toFlowable()) // get the executeRequest as Flowable
            .timeout(durationCap, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // apply a timeout policy
    }
```

And finally, you can subscribe to the `perform` at the place where you actually need to execute all this, As shown below

```
             perform()
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<HttpClientResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(HttpClientResponse httpClientResponse) {
                  // onNext will be triggered each time, whenever a request has executed and ready with result
                  // if you had 5 HTTP request, this can trigger 5 times with each "httpClientResponse" (if all calls were success)
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    // any error during the execution of these request,
                    // including a TimeoutException in case timeout happens in between
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                   // will be called finally if no errors happened and onNext delivered all the results
                }
            });
```